# How to make FlexLayout's height adjust to its content?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms application, I have a list of strings (minimum 1, maximum 4) that I want to display evenly in a column layout. Each column needs to have the same width and the content should expand so that the whole text is wrapped and visible. I know how I can do it using the `Grid` control using `Width="*"` on its columns.

I want to achieve the same result using `FlexLayout`, so I can bind the list of strings to `BindableLayout` and easily add and remove columns (I will not be displaying strings but a more complex layout in each column).

Using `FlexLayout.Grow` and `FlexLayout.Basis` I can get the `FlexLayout` to display evenly sized columns. The problem is making the `FlexLayout`'s height fit all the displayed labels. Only the first row of text is displayed.

Both the `Grid` and `FlexLayout` are wrapped in a `StackLayout`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label  Text="First label" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />

        <Label Text="Second label" Grid.Column="1"  BackgroundColor="Red"
               LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />

        <Label Text="Third label but with longer text" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Aqua"
               LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>

        <Label Text="Fourth label" BackgroundColor="Red"
               Grid.Column="3"   LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />

    </Grid>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue"></BoxView>

    <FlexLayout AlignItems="Stretch">
        <Label  Text="First label" 
                FlexLayout.Grow="1" 
                FlexLayout.Basis="0" 
                BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />

        <Label  Text="Second label" 
                FlexLayout.Grow="1" 
                FlexLayout.Basis="0" 
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />

        <Label  Text="Third label but with longer text" 
                FlexLayout.Grow="1" 
                FlexLayout.Basis="0" 
                BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />

        <Label  Text="Fourth label" 
                FlexLayout.Grow="1" 
                FlexLayout.Basis="0" 
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />

    </FlexLayout>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue"></BoxView>
</StackLayout>
```

[Grid and FlexLayout displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqBfQ.png)

I figured out that when setting the `HeightRequest` of the `FlexLayout` to a specific number (e.g. 150), everything works as expected - the row has a height of 150 and all the labels stretch out to fit that. So what I need is somehow specify `HeightRequest="Auto"` so that the row fits all the column's content without being set to a specific value

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You may need to set hightRequest for FlexLayout or Label in FlexLayout, or just use Grid, don't find other way to do this.

Comment: when you already have the solution as grid why are you exploring Flex

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi for the reason I'm describing: grid forces me to either declare all the columns in advance (XAML) or have me define all the markup dynamically in code behind. FlexLayout would allow me to bind to an IEnumerable to BindableLayout and just define a template for a single column through DataTempalte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FlexLayout**  will cut its child Elements . So in your case use Grid is the best solution .

> so I can bind the list of strings to BindableLayout and easily add and remove columns

If you want to display a collection of data I suggest that you could use **ListView** or **CollectionView**(if you want to let the collection scroll in Horizontal or display multi Columns in the same row) .

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:WidthConverter x:Key="WidthConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout x:Name="stack">
        <CollectionView x:Name="list"  >

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    

                        <Grid WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference stack},Path=Width,Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Label Text="111111" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"  />

                           

                        </Grid>

                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

#### in code behind

```
public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var width = (double)value;

            if(width>0)
            {
                return width * 0.25;
            }

            return 100;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

For more details you could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-list

Comment: This would be almost what I want. I tried using the collection view, but don't know how to have it display the bound items in one row, with all the dataTemplates having the same width (as in the provided screenshot). Add items to itemSource needs to be adding columns in the view, not rows.

Comment: Check my update answer  .If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: This makes the collection view add a column for each item in itemSource, but does not make them the same width as I'm adding independent grid controls for each item. Would there be a way so that when I have 4 items in itemSource, each dataTemplate would take up equal (25%) width?